# Searching for an dictionary value inside a list

Tags: python, dictionary

my method searches for a specific value through a list of dictionaries. I would like to expend it. It should return not only the found dictionary but also the index of the dictionary.

What do I have to modify?

**search method**

```
def search_user(self, user_id, data):
        return [element for element in data if element['id'] == user_id]
```

**input data**

```
[
    {
        "id": "12",
        "other": "stuff"
    },
    {
        "id": "987654321",
        "other": "stuff"
    }
]
```

---

**current return value**

```
# dictionary
{
        "id": "987654321",
        "other": "stuff"
}
```

**target return value**

```
# index of the dictionary, dictionary
[
    1,
    {
        "id": "987654321",
        "other": "stuff"
    }

]
```

Comment: You could use enumerate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use enumerate:

```
def search_user(self, user_id, data):
    return [(lv, element) for lv, element in enumerate(data) if element['id'] == user_id]
```

This will return a list of tuples, where the first element of each tuple is the index and the second the dictionary.